# How to remove NcFTP

Tags: macos, ftp, uninstall, osx-lion

I recently installed NcFTP but would like to uninstall it again as I have ended up not using it.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation (manual pages) will be installed to `/usr/share/man`.
You may then type `man ncft` at a shell prompt to read the manual, or view the documentation [online](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftp.html).

All programs will be installed to your `/usr/bin` directory.  Please note that an older version (2.4.3) of NcFTP may already be installed since it comes with the Mac OS X BSD Subsystem.  It will be overwritten by this installer.

The main program is simply called `ncftp`.  There are also separate utility programs for one-shot FTP operations (i.e. for shell scripts and command line junkies);  these include `ncftpget`, `ncftpput`, and `ncftpls`.  Run each command without any arguments to see the usage screen, or read the man page.

Also included is a batch processing daemon, `ncftpbatch`,which is invoked by the `bgget` command from `ncftp` and also the `-b` flag of `ncftpput` and `ncftpget`.

Lastly, the `ncftpbookmarks` program is a utility program to manipulate user's FTP bookmarks.